# Trust controller in X mode, seen but gives no input

Tags: usb, xorg, games, gamepad, joystick

I have a Trust GTX YULA controller which I would also like to use on my Ubuntu laptop.

The controller has a switch between Direct mode and X mode, where it pretends to be an XBOX controller. X mode works fine on Windows. I don't want to use D mode because the analog sticks provide discrete inputs in that mode, pretending to be buttons, and one overlaps with the ABXY buttons.

The output to `lsusb` contains this line:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
```

Which I assume is my controller since I have no other controllers. It is connected through an USB hub.

I have installed `jstest-gtk`, and it also sees the controller as an XBOX 360 pad, but clicking *properties* and pushing buttons on the controller does not make the corresponding software icons light up.

[image: window of `jstest-gtk', having selected *properties* of the only available controller]

I have tried using `xboxdrv`, but this is the output:

```
$ sudo xboxdrv
xboxdrv 0.8.8 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ 
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmail.com> 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details. 

Controller:        Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
Vendor/Product:    045e:028e
USB Path:          001:013
Controller Type:   Xbox360

Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
  /dev/input/js0
  /dev/input/event18

Press Ctrl-C to quit, use '--silent' to suppress the event output
[ERROR] USBController::on_read_data(): USB read failure: 32: LIBUSB_TRANSFER_ERROR
[ERROR] USBController::on_write_data(): USB write failure: 3: LIBUSB_TRANSFER_ERROR
```

With this running, `evtest` gives the following output (pushing buttons on the controller does nothing)

```
$ evtest /dev/input/event18
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver)"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 314 (BTN_SELECT)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
    Event code 316 (BTN_MODE)
    Event code 317 (BTN_THUMBL)
    Event code 318 (BTN_THUMBR)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
    Event code 3 (ABS_RX)
      Value      0
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
    Event code 4 (ABS_RY)
      Value      0
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
    Event code 9 (ABS_GAS)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 10 (ABS_BRAKE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

One user suggested removing `xserver-xorg-input-joystick.*`, but I don't have any installed.

How can I make my controller work?

Is [this site](https://html5gamepad.com) effective as a check?

Thank you.

Comment: Try selecting DInput mode using the switch on the back.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue was reported about xpad driver:
https://github.com/paroj/xpad/issues/119
The python srcipt (fixcontroller.py) mentioned in the description solved the problem. Here is a copy of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys


try:
    import usb.core
    import usb.util
except ImportError:
    print("First, install the pyusb module with PIP or your package manager.")
else:
    if os.geteuid() != 0:
        print("You need to run this script with sudo")
        sys.exit()

    dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)

    for d in dev:
        if d.idVendor == 0x045e and d.idProduct == 0x028e:
            d.ctrl_transfer(0xc1, 0x01, 0x0100, 0x00, 0x14)
finally:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me, can you explain this line ? d.ctrl_transfer(0xc1, 0x01, 0x0100, 0x00, 0x14) , i think the original script creator analyzed these hex codes from usbmon and seems like these are universal